# asymptotic bound on number of primes from 1 to n

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $\pi(m, n)$ denote the set of prime numbers in the interval $[m,n]$.

I already proved that: $$\prod_{p\in \pi(m+1, 2m)} p \leq \binom{2m}{m} $$

$$\prod_{p\in \pi(1, n)} p \leq {4^n} $$

now, I need to show that -

$${|\pi(1,n)| \leq O(n/log(n))}$$

any thoughts? would appreciate your help.